# Using ui-grid constants to disable scrollbars

Tags: angularjs, scrollbar, angular-ui-grid

With the latest version of ui-grid (v3.0.0-rc.16) it is possible to turn the horizontal and vertical scrollbar off seperately. 
I got this working by exchanging

```
$scope.gridOptions.enableScrollbars = false;
```

with

```
$scope.gridOptions.enableHorizontalScrollbar = 0;
$scope.gridOptions.enableVerticalScrollbar = 0;
```

In the sources of ui-grid there are three Constants defined for the scrollbars:

```
scrollbars: {
  NEVER: 0,
  ALWAYS: 1,
  WHEN_NEEDED: 2
}
```

Facing the fact that ui-grid is still unstable and changed very often, i would feel more comfortable using those constants instead of the specific values. But how can i access them ?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/h0ewAZK616rKCH3T62te

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Got my answer on github:

All I needed to do was to pass uiGridConstants to my controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',function($scope,uiGridConstants) {
    ...

    $scope.gridOptions.enableHorizontalScrollbar = uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER;

    ...
})
```

Comment: Where do you find all the options available for `uiGridConstants`?

Comment: I console.log'd it: is it just avg, count, max, min & sum? I feel like stddev should be in there

Comment: The most reliable way to get the information you need concerning ui-grid is to read the source code and to ask the developers on git hub. :)

Comment: Problem is this doesn't disable `bind-scroll-vertical` and `ui-grid` continues to swallow some scroll events.

Answer (score 15):

With John Papa style:

```
ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants'];
function ExampleController($scope, uiGridConstants) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.gridOptions = {
        enableHorizontalScrollbar : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
        enableVerticalScrollbar   : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER
    };
}
```

Comment: This hides the scrollbars but does not stop `uiGrid` from interfering with scroll events.

Answer (score 12):

A workaround for this (since WHEN_NEEDED is currently disabled) is to set `enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0` on your gridOptions and then in your stylesheet have the following:

```
.ui-grid .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-viewport {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

Now the horizontal scroll bar only displays when needed.